# Proof of Liouville's theorem for harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In complex analysis, Liouville's theorem is that every bounded entire function is constant. To prove it, Cauchy intergral formula is used$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds$$ where C is circle with radius of R, and $|f'(z)|\le \frac{M}{2\pi R}$ by using bounded condition($|f(z)|\le M)$ and Cauchy's differentiation formula. Then, $f'(z)$ goes to $0 $ as R goes to infinity. So, f(z) is constant.
The same method can be used in proving Liouville's theorem for harmonic function?

In Partial differential equation, Liouville's theorem is that
 $u(\mathbf x)$ is constant if $u(\mathbf x)$ is harmonic function in $\Bbb R^N (N=2,3) $ and $u(\mathbf x)$ is bounded by $M>0$.

By mean value principle, $$u(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{|\partial B_R(\mathbf x)|}\int_{\partial B_R(\mathbf x)}u(s)ds$$ Then, how can I differentiate $u(\mathbf x)$?

Comment: If you're just looking for a proof of Liouville's theorem for harmonic functions, then just use the fact that over a simply-connected domain, every harmonic function is equal to the real part of a holomorphic function.

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan, your idea only works for $\dim = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the same method can be used. A Cauchy-type estimate on the derivative of a harmonic function holds, and the proof is very much like that for the holomorphic case.

Let $B$ denote the open unit ball in $\mathbb R ^n.$ Claim: There is a constant $C$ such that

$$|\nabla u (0)| \le C\sup_{\partial B} |u|$$

for any function harmonic on a neighborhood of $\overline B.$

Proof: This comes from differentiating through the integral sign in the Poisson integral representation of $u$ on the unit sphere. Doing this will give an appropriate bound on $|\partial u/\partial x_k (0)|,$ $k=1,\dots ,n.$ This proves the claim.

Now suppose $u$ is harmonic on $\mathbb R ^n$ and $|u|\le M$ everywhere. For any $r>0,$ we can set $u_r(x) = u(rx).$ Note each $u_r$ is harmonic on $\mathbb 
R^n$ and $|u_r|\le M.$ Using the above, we get

$$|\nabla u_r (0)| \le C\sup_{\partial B} |u_r|\le C\cdot M.$$

But $\nabla u_r (0) = r\nabla u (0).$ This shows $|\nabla u (0)| \le CM/r.$ Now let $r\to \infty$ to see $|\nabla u (0)| =0.$ Finally, apply this to any translate of $u$ to see $|\nabla u | =0$ everywhere. This implies $u$ is constant.

Answer (score 3):

Quote (the full paper!) of [A Proof of Liouville's Theorem](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4.pdf):

> Consider a bounded harmonic function on Euclidean space. Since
> it is harmonic, its value at any point is its average over any sphere,
> and hence over any ball, with the point as center. Given two points,
> choose two balls with the given points as centers and of equal radius.
> If the radius is large enough, the two balls will coincide except for an arbitrarily small proportion of their volume. Since the function is
> bounded, the averages of it over the two balls are arbitrarily close,
> and so the function assumes the same value at any two points. Thus a bounded harmonic function on Euclidean space is a constant.