# Why is $\nabla u (r\cdot 0) = r\nabla u (0)$ true for a harmonic function $u$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I've stumbled across an [older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2797191/483790) here trying to solve the same problem the asker of the post had. The solution that was provided stated that for a harmonic function $u$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $\nabla u (r\cdot0) = r\nabla u (0)$ for any $r > 0$. I'm not quite sure that this is true. Here's a counter example that I found:

- $u((x,y)) = e^x \sin(y)$ is harmonic
- $\nabla u((x,y)) = \begin{pmatrix}
  e^x \sin(y) \\
  e^x \cos(y)
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
- $\nabla u((r\cdot 0,r\cdot 0)) = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\ 1
  \end{pmatrix} \neq r\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\ 1
  \end{pmatrix} = r\nabla u((0,0))$

Am I missing something or is the claim indeed wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably got the defintion of $u_r$ wrong. $u_r(x,y)=e^{rx}\sin (ry)$ and $\nabla u_r(0,0)=(0,r)$ and not $(0,1)$

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks a lot!