# Specific proof for Liouville’s theorem for dimension $2$ using Liouville’s theorem from complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am aware of Liouville’s theorem from complex analysis that says that any holomorphic function that is bounded and entire must be constant. I want to use it to prove that any positive harmonic function $u: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ must be constant. I found the question below which seems relevant.

On [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2797061/602386) a commenter writes,

> If you're just looking for a proof of Liouville's theorem for harmonic
> functions, then just use the fact that over a simply-connected domain,
> every harmonic function is equal to the real part of a holomorphic
> function.

It is said that this only works for dimension two, which is fine since that is specifically what I want. But I’m not sure how to relate the harmonic function being positive to the holomorphic function being bounded.

Specifically, if I write

$$f=u+iv$$

for $f$ holomorphic and $u$ as above, I’m not sure how to get any conditions on $v$, e.g. whether it is positive, bounded, etc. The only thing I know is it is harmonic.

How can I proceed to go from Liouville’s theorem from complex analysis to showing $u$ is constant?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/229312/42969

Comment: My holomorphic function $u$ is not necessarily bounded, just positive @MartinR

Comment: The title of that question was misleading. The question and the answers apply to holomorphic functions whose real part is bounded above (or bounded below). I have now edited the title to make that clear.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, I see now. Yes, this is what I need. Thank you.